# Cordova hide android source code

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

i am developing an mobile application(using Cordova and JQuery mobile) and i found that ios,android can anyone view my source code as is !!!

this is very dangerous for me , so i have used Cordova plugin for that

cordova-plugin-crypt-file

and it's pretty simple and good for ios , but for android i got problem with ajax and it's not work any more and always gave me 404 http error but ios using same everything works just fine

so my question is : how can i secure my source code with effecting other's

thank you

Comment: Thi s a tradeoff of not using a compiled language.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of people have asked this type of question and basicaly you cannot get full protection on your app.

You can do a combination of the following

- Obfuscate - there are reverse obfuscators
- Encrypt - you may need to keep the encryption JS and the key on the app, unless you make the app connect online every time it is opened. If you are doing this anyway then is may be better to port sensitive code online and run it there.  If your app decrypts the code at run time then someone may still see it via developer.
- Paid protection

None of these will completely protect your code but the latter probably does the best.  You do have to pay and I have not seen any independant write up on its efficacy.  If you look at the links below have a look at the encryope ios one, this is the best so far.

Here are some links to other question on this

[obfuscate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194397/how-can-i-obfuscate-protect-javascript)

[encrypt](http://wordpress.medicationsafetyfoundation.org/?p=578)

[encrypt ios](http://oleksiy.pro/2012/12/27/cordova-ios-security/)

[paid](http://javascriptobfuscator.com/)